# How to retrieve values from a text

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve X_coordinates and Y_coordinates from a txt file that look like that :

```
text =POLYGON ((252291.12483051314 1116798.7306648178,294319.54664371524 1122497.4997242352,297881.2773058511 1084030.8085731687,296456.5850409968 1022769.0411844333,240893.58671167865 988576.4268279299,190317.0113093506 957945.5431335622,188179.97291206918 985014.696165794,274373.8549357549 1048413.5019518109,252291.12483051314 1116798.7306648178))
```

there is a space between values that split X and Y coordinates.

I have tried :

```
     X_coord = []
     Y_coord = []
     for i in range (10 ,len(text)-2):
       Flag_X = True
       Flag_Y = False
       if (text[i] != " " and Flag_X == True) : 
          X_coord += (text[i])
       if (text[i] == " "):
          Flag_X = False
          Flag_Y = True
          X_coord += ","
       if (text[i] != "," and Flag_Y == True):
          Y_coord += text[i]
       if (text[i] == ","):
          Flag_X = True
          Flag_Y = False
          Y_coord += ","
```

The code gives an output ['2',5','2',...] and I need an output like that

```
X_coordinates= [252291.12483051314, 294319.54664371524 … ]
Y_coordinates = [1116798.7306648178, 1122497.4997242352 ... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.strip` and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
X_coord = []
Y_coord = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for cords in line.lstrip("POLYGON").strip().strip("()").split(","):
            x, y = cords.split()
            X_coord.append(float(x))
            Y_coord.append(float(y))
print(X_coord)
print(Y_coord)
```

**Output:**

```
[252291.12483051314, 294319.54664371524, 297881.2773058511, 296456.5850409968, 240893.58671167865, 190317.0113093506, 188179.97291206918, 274373.8549357549, 252291.12483051314]
[1116798.7306648178, 1122497.4997242352, 1084030.8085731687, 1022769.0411844333, 988576.4268279299, 957945.5431335622, 985014.696165794, 1048413.5019518109, 1116798.7306648178]
```

---

*Content in Txt*

```
POLYGON ((252291.12483051314 1116798.7306648178,294319.54664371524 1122497.4997242352,297881.2773058511 1084030.8085731687,296456.5850409968 1022769.0411844333,240893.58671167865 988576.4268279299,190317.0113093506 957945.5431335622,188179.97291206918 985014.696165794,274373.8549357549 1048413.5019518109,252291.12483051314 1116798.7306648178))
```

Answer (score 0):

If list is not necessary, you can use this one-liner *(it returns tuples)*.

```
coordinates_x, coordinates_y = zip(*(coord.split(" ") for coord in text[10:-2].split(",")))
```

Output:

```
coordinates_x = ('252291.12483051314', '294319.54664371524', '297881.2773058511', '296456.5850409968', '240893.58671167865', '190317.0113093506', '188179.97291206918', '274373.8549357549', '252291.12483051314')
coordinates_y = ('1116798.7306648178', '1122497.4997242352', '1084030.8085731687', '1022769.0411844333', '988576.4268279299', '957945.5431335622', '985014.696165794', '1048413.5019518109', '1116798.7306648178')
```